# Postgresql LISTEN / NOTIFY recap

Tags: postgresql

I created the following trigger to track all the changes on a postgres table.

```
DROP TRIGGER tr_request_update_notify ON requests;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION request_update_notify() RETURNS trigger as $$
BEGIN  
  PERFORM pg_notify('request_update_notify', json_build_object('table', TG_TABLE_NAME, 'id', NEW.id, 'event', NEW.event, 'type', TG_OP)::text);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER tr_request_update_notify AFTER UPDATE or INSERT ON requests FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE request_update_notify();
```

Another application will listen to the connection and apply suitable treatment for each event.

If an event happens and my application is not up, the event will never be processed. Is there a way to have a recap of all missed notification?

Answer (score 3):

Notification are not stored anywhere, they are just sent to whatever session is listening on the same notification channel. But seeing that you are in a database, why not store the notification in a table and then the listeners simply poll that table when they are active. You can then also use straight `json` instead of casting it to `text`. Not as "automatic" as `NOTIFY/LISTEN` but otherwise pretty fool-proof.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION request_update_notify() RETURNS trigger as $$
BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO my_notifications (channel, message_time, notification)
  VALUES ('request_update_notify', CURRENT_TIME,
          json_build_object('table', TG_TABLE_NAME,
                            'id',    NEW.id,
                            'event', NEW.event,
                            'type',  TG_OP)
  );
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Or even merge the idea of a table and notify so new events come as notify and old ones can be read from the table. That way there is no need to poll

Comment: The idea behind using NOTIFY/LISTEN is to avoid polling tables. I will probably use the suggested solution partially and manage a sequence number. Thus, at startup, my application will handle all the notifications it missed (can be found out using sequence number) before and then listen to the DB again.